# show a custom message every 10 second from background service

Tags: java, android, service, android-broadcastreceiver, android-toast

I want to implement a feature in my application to show a custom message after every 10-20 second also when app is not started and phone is in wake up state...

I am sharing you a screenshot and a refer app which has this functionality in their app I want same functionality in my app.

App name is **Auto- Athkar for muslims**

[image]

Comment: You have to create background service that run in background and after 10 second you send notification,

Comment: this is a notification or something other ???

Comment: didn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

An android toast could work in a while loop?
Your have to register when the app is pushed minimised which is normally done by

```
public void onPause () {
}
```

You'd have to start a service in your Application class to run it constantly. Even if user force closes then it should run.
Create your own service class :

```
public class Servicey extends Service {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int begin(Intent intent, int flags, int beginId) {
    // do that shiny stuff with toasts
    return super.begin(intent, flags, beginId);
}
```

Then start your service on the `onCreate()` of your activity

```
startService(new Intent(this, Servicey.class));
```